# Parametric Plot of coupled differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I am able to plot a graph of all the differential equations, but I'd like a parametric plot of each individual one. 
Here is what I have so far.

```
new = Join[
Table[x[i]''[t] == - x[i][t] + 
  0.1*(x[i + 1][t] - 2*x[i][t] + x[i - 1][t]), {i, 1, 
 9}], {x[0]'[t] == -x[0][t], x[10]'[t] == x[9][t], x[0][0] == 0, 
x[1][0] == 1}, Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, 2, 10}], 
Table[x[i]'[0] == 1, {i, 1, 9}]];

Solt[i_] = NDSolve[new, Table[x[i][t], {i, 0, 10}], {t, 10}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[i][t], {i, 10}] /. Solt[i_]], {t, 0, 10}]

Table[ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[{x[i][t], x[i]'[t]} /. Solt[i_]], {t, 0, 10}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

What is wrong with the parametric plot. I've done this one before (without the added forcing term). It won't show up.

Comment: That's easy to fix: **(a)** leave out the underscore in `Solt[i_]` except in the first instance where you need a pattern in the definition. **(b)** Leave out the `[t]` in `NDSolve[new, Table[x[i][t]...` (I think I added that in my [previous answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26903/245) to your question, but it's not what you were expecting in the post-processing). With the additional `[t]` argument the replacement rule `Solt` doesn't get applied to derivatives of the functions..

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies only in the way you define the solution `Solt`. The index `i` in `Solt[i_]` isn't appropriate because `Solt` is supposed to be a single `List`.

Apart from this, you have two options to specify what `NDSolve` returns: either the functions `x[i]` (which yield numerical values when *applied* to a numerical argument) or the expressions `x[i][t]` which yield numerical values when `t` is simply *replaced* by a number. From the `Plot` functions in your example, it is clear that you expect the former, i.e., `x[i]`, because in the second set of plots we need to form the `Derivative`: `x[i]'[t]`. This is not matched by a the patterns in `Solt` if it contains replacement rules of the form `x[i][t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]`. So we have to instruct `NDSolve` to return the solutions as functions:

```
new = Join[
   Table[x[i]''[t] == -x[i][t] + 
      0.1*(x[i + 1][t] - 2*x[i][t] + x[i - 1][t]), {i, 1, 
     9}], {x[0]'[t] == -x[0][t], x[10]'[t] == x[9][t], x[0][0] == 0, 
    x[1][0] == 1}, Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, 2, 10}], 
   Table[x[i]'[0] == 1, {i, 1, 9}]];


Solt = NDSolve[new, Table[x[i], {i, 0, 10}], {t, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[i][t], {i, 10}] /. Solt], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: solutions]

```
Table[ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{x[i][t], x[i]'[t]} /. Solt], {t, 0, 10}], {i, 1, 10}]
```

[image: derivatives]

This is not the only way to do things, though. If you have instead defined

```
Solt = NDSolve[new, Table[x[i][t], {i, 0, 10}], {t, 10}];
```

then it's still possible to do the plots you wanted. We just have to form the desired derivatives of the returned *expressions*. This can be done using `D` instead of `Derivative` (the latter is what the `'` operation corresponds to):

```
Map[
 ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{#1, D[#1, t]}],
   {t, 0, 10}] &,
 Table[x[i][t], {i, 10}] /. Solt[[1]]
 ]
```

which produces the same plot as above. Here I moved the formation of the `Table` to the end so that the `ParametricPlot` can use it to pait each `x[i][t]` with the corresponding derivative.

In the last code snippet, there is another change compared to your code: I replaced `Solt` by `Solt[[1]]`. This is because the solution `Solt` as defined above is a list of lists, and we only want a single list so that the shape of the `Table` is flat and leads to a list of different `ParametricPlots` when `Map` runs over its first level.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help!